# How to add an inline element into flexforms and get it work

Tags: typo3, inline, typo3-8.x, flexform

I created a field of type inline in my flexForm config in a TYPO3 8.7.24.
i added the config with forein_table and foreign_field.
the foreign_field was added in the foreign_table with type passtrough.
now i think, if i save my record, the uid of the record should saved in the passtrough field. but, nothing is saved in the passtrough field. So TYPO3 cant find a relation between the record and the irre record.

Is my thinking completely wrong or is this not working with flexforms.
thanks for every hint

```
<settings.networks>
  <label>Networks</label>
  <config type="array">
    <type>inline</type>
    <foreign_table>tx_xxx_domain_model_networks</foreign_table
    <foreign_field>foreign_uid</foreign_field>
    <maxitems>9999</maxitems>
  </config>
</settings.networks>
```

Comment: After talking to some other people from the TYPO3-Community i solved this issue.
Its not enouth to have one field in the childTable to identify which child belongs to the parent. Maybe there are more than one IRRE config the parentId is not enough.

Here is a very good example for what i was looking for.
[link](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/core/Tests/Functional/Fixtures/Extensions/irre_tutorial/Configuration/FlexForms/tt_content_flexform.xml)

ps. Thanks for the downvotes... But why?

Comment: I really don't know about the downvotes. Maybe someone just hates FlexForms. But if you found an answer, can you write a real answer and accept it? That way the question disappears from list of questions without answer and it makes it easier for others to find open questions. Thanks.

Comment: I wrote how i solved the problem. I posted a link which describes a solution for my problem. Why is this not a real answer? @SybillePeters

Comment: This is not a must-do. It is a suggestion. I meant: post the text as "answer to your question" on StackOverflow by filling out the the  form "Your Answer" and clicking "Post your answer". Then accept it by clicking on the checkmark. You might think it's unnecessary because people find the information in the comments, so why should you post the same information as answer, but there are advantages: people can vote, you can use formatting, add links. Question no longer appears as "unanswered" in list.

Comment: It's ok to answer your own question, especially if there are 0 answers. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @MaikHagenbruch your link above is outdated, that is why its more helpful to post the answer here for other people looking for the same issue